# Cant boot to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 today with disk erase too, my problem is after installation it again asks me to install/go on without installing.
And when i unplug the USB then it just says `no medium found` or something like that with a black screen.

I tried reinstalling couple of times, it didnt work.
I also tried boot repair but it gives me this error `GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.` so i try to make a 10mb unformatted partion, but then manage flags option is greyed out so i cant choose it.

I am writing this from the `try without installing` option so thats working.
I need help really.

EDIT: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11610139/ this is the log thingy, as you can guess i am a beginner in all these

EDIT 2:I finally got boot repair to repair it, so it says. but it still will say `no medium present` and wont boot. this is the new log http://paste.ubuntu.com/11610650/

Answer (score 1):

To fix this:
All you have to do is change from UEFI to legacy.